# Hibernate SELECT query with LIKE %

Tags: hibernate, jpql

I need a HQL or JPQL for the following query:

```
select * from customer where customer_name like '%ROB%'
```

I am using Query Manager for JPQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.stpe.se/2008/07/hibernate-hql-like-query-named-parameters/ says you should include the `%` symbol in the parameter itself, not the query.

e.g.:

```
String query = "from user u where u.name like :name"
getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(query, "name", '%' + str + '%');
```